# Unit testing redirect in controller to external website

Tags: visualforce, unit-test

A Visualforce page has a custom controller that navigates to an external website after the' command button is pressed. What is the recommended way to test this functionality? Will the ApexPages.getCurrentPage() work?

Comment: Just call the method. It would be better if you share what you did so far

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The normal pattern is that the method you call as the button's action method returns the page to go to:

```
public class MyController {
    ...
    public PageReference myMethod() {
        ...
        return new PageReference('https://...');
    }
}
```

so the test can just call that method and assert the URL that is returned:

```
    MyController c = new MyController();
    ...
    PageReference pr = c.myMethod();
    System.assertEquals('https://...', pr.getUrl());
```